# How would I grab certain information from HTML scraping, if the website returns it as not loaded?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, parsing, screen-scraping

When I write the HTML to a file, and open the file, it says "The inventory is not available" I tried using a user-agent, but I had no luck. Any help?
 The result I was hoping for is to grab the entire inventory, and print out the list of a desired page on their inventory to the listbox. (Windows Forms Application, HtmlAgilityPack)

```
namespace projectWFA
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string selectedCurrency;
        public string urlBase = "http://www.steamcommunity.com/id/";
        public string text_username;

        // HTMLAGILITYPACK
        public HtmlWeb htmlweb;
        public HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldocument_pageInventory;
        public HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldocument;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboboxCurrency.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboboxPlaceHolder1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboboxPlaceHolder2.SelectedIndex = 0;

            // WEB STUFF
            htmlweb = new HtmlWeb();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedCurrency = comboboxCurrency.Items[comboboxCurrency.SelectedIndex].ToString();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("selCur: " + selectedCurrency);
        }

        private void buttonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelPrintUsername.Text = "Loading webpage.. Please wait..";
            // LOAD WEBPAGE
            htmldocument = htmlweb.Load(urlBase + textboxProfileLink.Text);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Link: " + urlBase + textboxProfileLink.Text);

            if (htmldocument != null)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Found profile");
                HtmlNode node_username = htmldocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='actual_persona_name']");

                if (node_username != null)
                {

                    text_username = node_username.InnerText;
                    labelPrintUsername.Text = text_username + "'s Inventory";
                    listboxItems.Items.Clear();

                    htmldocument_pageInventory = htmlweb.Load(urlBase + textboxProfileLink.Text + "/inventory/");

                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\asd.html", htmldocument_pageInventory.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
                }
            }
            else if (htmldocument == null)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Couldn't find profile");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the page as it would be from using a browser, use this instead:

```
        string data  = "";
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            data = client.DownloadString(url);
        }
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        doc.Load(stream);
```

Comment: how would I call a node from the doc.Load(stream); ?

Comment: i believe the process is the same as what you are doing now... ``HtmlNode myNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode( ... );``

Comment: Hmm. for some reason it still outputs as though it didn't load the inventory. I get a "This inventory is not available at this time. Please try again later."

Comment: not sure then. This is the only way i know to get the HTML content as it would be if you were to use a web browser. Maybe the website uses cookies to figure out who you are and load the inventory or something like that. Maybe it uses some JavaScript "deterrent" for such things as what you're trying to do to submit a request to the server to load the contents, and without a browser, it simply doesn't load. I just don't know enough about what you're trying to do and on which site to help you more than this...

Comment: I think i need to use cookies. I'll learn how. Thank you for your help it is much appreciated!